# SaveFileDialog saves as blank ext? - C#

Tags: c#

So I got the hang of doing OpenFileDialog, now I can't seem to understand SaveFileDialog. Looked at a few pages and each of them have there own ways of doing it, but none of them get down to the point of saving the text that is in the richtextbox to a file.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Stream myStream;
            SaveFileDialog exportdialogue = new SaveFileDialog();

            exportdialogue.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt*";
            exportdialogue.FilterIndex = 2;
            exportdialogue.RestoreDirectory = true;

            if (exportdialogue.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if ((myStream = exportdialogue.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    StreamWriter wText = new StreamWriter(myStream);

                    wText.Write("Some Text");

                    myStream.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Using a richtextbox, and a normal button, also "using System.IO;" (For the Stream )

I am trying to get the button to use SaveFileDialog so it can export the content within the richtextbox to a text file.

Issue:
Unsure what I need to do from here to make it save contents from the rich text box.
Don't know why SaveFileDialog saves files with no extension when a filter is in place.

Comment: What is the point of having reachtextbox if you saving its content as text.  You will lose all the formatting if you do that.

Comment: @Max it does keep format... http://puu.sh/5qDmN.png

Comment: not really. in rtb you can apply formats to your text similar to word. If the only purpose is to [keep tabs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.acceptstab(v=vs.110).aspx) you can use plain text box to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set:

```
exportdialogue.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt*";
```

which only contains ONE filter, but you set:

```
exportdialogue.FilterIndex = 2;
```

which means to use the SECOND filter. (FilterIndex is 1-based).

If you set FilterIndex = 1, your file should have the extension .txt

Comment: I changed it to FilterIndex = 1; and it still does not save as a .txt

Comment: Also, set DefaultExt :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `using {}` block to solve the issue:

Try this:

```
            SaveFileDialog exportdialogue = new SaveFileDialog();

            exportdialogue.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt*";
            exportdialogue.FilterIndex = 2;
            exportdialogue.RestoreDirectory = true;


            if (exportdialogue.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                using( Stream myStream = exportdialogue.OpenFile())
                {
                    StreamWriter wText = new StreamWriter(myStream);

                    wText.Write("Some Text");
                    wText.Close();


                }
            }
```

Comment: Certainly. :-) Your answer is wrong. `using` doesn't solve the problem. (There's precisely one filter in place, but the code sets `FlterIndex = 2`.)

Answer (score -1):

you need to use savefile method of reach textbox and pass to it the filename from savedialogbox.

```
reachtextbox.SaveFile(exportdialogue.FileName);
```

ps: it will be something like above code.